# /etc/fstabの内容がホストの到達可能性に影響する

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

*質問を書いている途中で問題が解決したので、回答も併せて投稿させていただきます。*

Raspberry Piをヘッドレスで運用しているのですが、`/etc/fstab`の内容が、RPiにSSHログインできるか否か、pingが通るか否かに影響してしまいます。

### 環境

RPi: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
OS: Raspbian (jessie) (クリーンインストール)
ヘッドレス
ルータのDHCPで固定IPを割当てている。

`/etc/fstab`の内容（コメント行は削除）

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

UUID=<外付けHDD_aのUUID>    /media/<外付けHDD_aのUUID>  ntfs    rw,user,nosuid,nodev,uid=1002,gid=1002,dmask=0002   0   0
```

### 問題

外付けHDD_aを接続**せず**にRPiを起動すると、固定IPに対するpingがHost Unreachableになります(ルータのログに本来あるはずのIPを割り当てたというメッセージも無し)。ところが外付けHDD_aを接続して起動したり、`/etc/fstab`の最後の行をコメントアウトしておくとSSH含め正常に通信できます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jessieのリリースノート](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/s390x/release-notes/ch-information.ja.html#systemd-auto-mounts-incompat)の以下の記述を参考に、`/etc/fstab`に`nofail`オプションを追加したところ問題が解決しました。

> 新しい標準 init システムである systemd-sysv は、起動中の "auto" マウントの失敗について、sysvinit と比べて厳しく取り扱います。("nofail" オプション無しの) "auto" マウントに失敗した場合、systemd は起動を続けるのではなく非常時のシェルに落ちます。
>
> /etc/fstab 中に記載されている全てのリムーバブルドライブまたは "optional" なマウントポイント (例: 必須ではないネットワークドライブ) については、"noauto" または "nofail" いずれかのオプションの付加を推奨します。

```
UUID=<外付けHDD_aのUUID>    /media/<外付けHDD_aのUUID>  ntfs    rw,user,nosuid,nodev,nofail,uid=1002,gid=1002,dmask=0002   0   0
```

jessieでsystemdに移行したこと、wheezy時代の`fstab`をそのまま使っていたこと、ヘッドレスな環境のため外側たら見た状況しか分からなかったことが原因でした。